# Why is C jumping to the next printf instead of waiting for scanf?

Tags: c, file

**Firstly, here's my code:**

```
typedef struct Customer {
    char name[50];
    char billing_address[100];
    char phone_number[15];
    double amount_paid;
    double amount_due;
    char date[20];
} Customer;

Customer customer;

printf("CREATE A CUSTOMER PROFILE\n=========================\n");

printf("Name: ");
scanf("%s", customer.name);

printf("Billing Address: ");
scanf("%s", customer.billing_address);

printf("Phone Number: ");
scanf("%s", customer.phone_number);

printf("Amount Paid: ");
scanf("%lf", &customer.amount_paid);

printf("Amount Due: ");
scanf("%lf", &customer.amount_due);

printf("Payment Date: ");
scanf("%s", customer.date);

if (strlen(customer.name) == 0 || strlen(customer.billing_address) == 0 || strlen(customer.phone_number) == 0 || strlen(customer.date) == 0) {
    printf("All fields must be filled in!");
    create_customer_profile(is_admin);
}

FILE *file = fopen("customers.txt", "ab+");

fprintf(file, "[%s], [%s], [%s], [%lf], [%lf], [%s]", customer.name, customer.billing_address, customer.phone_number, customer.amount_paid, customer.amount_due, customer.date);

printf("The record for the customer has been saved successfully!");
```

So basically, I was testing my application after writing this code. Here's a view at the console:

```
CREATE A CUSTOMER PROFILE
=========================
Name: Hassan
Billing Address: Jalan Barat
Phone Number: Amount Paid: 011111111
Amount Due: 200
Payment Date: "12/12/2000"
The record for the customer has been saved successfully!
Process finished with exit code 0
```

As you see above, instead of waiting for Phone Number, the system jumps on to Amount Paid on the same line. Here's my file output:

[Hassan], [Jalan], [Barat], [11111111.000000], [200.000000], ["12/12/2000"]

For some reason, the phone number was filled with "Barat" instead of the address having "Jalan Barat." I would love some help on why C behaves this way.

**UPDATE:**

Using this input:

```
CREATE A CUSTOMER PROFILE
=========================
Name: hahah
Billing Address: lmfaooooooo
Phone Number: 01011010101001
Amount Paid: 010101
Amount Due: 393993
Payment Date: 24/12/2018
The record for the customer has been saved successfully!
Process finished with exit code 0
```

As you can see above, I did not include a space in the billing address field, and so, it works fine with this output in the file:

```
[hahah], [lmfaooooooo], [01011010101001], [10101.000000], [393993.000000], [24/12/2018]
```

**UPDATE 2:**

**Code Updated:**

printf("CREATE A CUSTOMER PROFILE\n=========================\n");

```
printf("Name: ");
fgets(customer.name, 50, stdin);

printf("Billing Address: ");
fgets(customer.billing_address, 100, stdin);

printf("Phone Number: ");
scanf("%s", customer.phone_number);

printf("Amount Paid: ");
scanf("%lf", &customer.amount_paid);

printf("Amount Due: ");
scanf("%lf", &customer.amount_due);

printf("Payment Date: ");
scanf("%s", customer.date);
```

**Input:**

```
CREATE A CUSTOMER PROFILE
=========================
Name: Billing Address: test
Phone Number: 011111
Amount Paid: 10000
Amount Due: 50000
Payment Date: 12/05/2019
The record for the customer has been saved successfully!
Process finished with exit code 0
```

**Output:**

```
[
], [test
], [011111], [10000.000000], [50000.000000], [12/05/2019]
```

I used `fgets` as suggested, but as you see, for the name, it only reads a line break. How would I solve this issue?

Comment: `%s` reads `Any number of non-whitespace characters, stopping at the first whitespace character found.`

Comment: Maybe you should do some research. Try reading the manpage for `[f]scanf()`, particularly the `%s` conversion specifier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `"%s"` format for [`scanf` (and family)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) reads a ***space delimited*** word. If you want to read more than one word, you either need to use the `"%["` format (which can be rather complex), or read the whole line with [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets).

Remember that the previous `scanf` call will leave the ending newline in the buffer, so you need to read and discard it before calling `fgets`.

Comment: Thanks. Worked. (y)

Answer (score 0):

From `man scanf`

```
   s      Matches a sequence of non-white-space characters; the next pointer must be a pointer to character array that is long  enough  to
          hold  the  input  sequence  and the terminating null byte ('\0'), which is added automatically.  The input string stops at white
          space or at the maximum field width, whichever occurs first.
```

Basically the line `scanf("%s", customer.billing_address);` will read until the first space. Then the next scanf will read the rest.

Comment: See answer from Some programmer dude". You can use for example fgets function